# Caffe ScaleLayer does not broadcast

Tags: broadcast, caffe

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/doxygen/classcaffe_1_1ScaleLayer.html says: ScaleLayer computes a product of two input Blobs, with the shape of the latter Blob "broadcast" to match the shape of the former. Equivalent to tiling the latter Blob, then computing the elementwise product.
But when I use the following code, an error occurs:

---------------------test.prototxt---------------------

```
name: "test"
input: "data1"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 5
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input: "data2"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
layer {
    name: "scale-layer"
    type: "Scale"
    bottom: "data1"
    bottom: "data2"
    top: "scale-top"
}
```

-----------------------------test code---------------------------------

```
import numpy as np
import caffe
data1 = np.random.random((1, 5, 1, 1))
data2 = np.random.random((1, 1, 1, 1))

caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

net = caffe.Net('test.prototxt', caffe.TEST)
net.blobs['data1'].data[...] = data1
net.blobs['data2'].data[...] = data2

ret = net.forward()
for k, v in ret.iteritems():
    print k
    print v.shape
```

-----------------------------error---------------------------------
I0827 12:28:25.427806 23384 net.cpp:399] scale-layer -> scale-top
F0827 12:28:25.427839 23384 scale_layer.cpp:80] Check failed: bottom[0]->num_axes() >= axis_ + scale->num_axes() (4 vs. 5) scale blob's shape extends past bottom[0]'s shape when applied starting with bottom[0] axis = 1
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted